# How to add space for item inside the ComboBox in UWP?

Tags: c#, combobox, enums, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ComboBox binded to some enum type. I'm wondering how to add space for the enum items. I tried to use converter, but failed.
The enum type is like this

```
public enum MaxEEAge
{
    TwoWeeks = 0,
    OneMonth = 1,
    ThreeMonths = 2,
    SixMonths = 3,
    All = 4,
}
```

I want the ComboBox show something like "Two Weeks" instead of TwoWeeks

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options,

Add a `[Description]` attribute then fetch it when needed:

```
[Description("Two weeks")]
TwoWeeks = 0
```

or

Implement some method like [ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName.html) in Unity.

Comment: Adding [Description] seems doesn't work for my case but I make a class that contains the enum and description string and write a converter to achieve the same effects. Use collection instead of enum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use collection instead of enum like this

```
    public class MaxXXAgeMembers
        {
            public MaxXXAge MaxXXAge { get; private set; }
            public string Description { get; private set; }

            public static readonly IReadOnlyList<MaxXXAgeMembers> Options = new ReadOnlyCollection<MaxXXAgeMembers>(new[]
            {
                new MaxXXAgeMembers { MaxXXAge =  MaxXXAge.OneDay, Description = Strings.SettingSync_OneDay},
.......
            });

            public static MaxXXAgeMembers FromMaxXXAge(MaxXXAge maxXXAge)
            {
                return Options.First(option => option.MaxXXAge == maxXXAge);
            }
        }
```

Write your own converter by using the FromMaxXXAge, it would be easy to achieve this.

Bind to this

```
public IReadOnlyList<MaxXXAgeMembers> MaxXXAgeMemberGroup { get { return MaxXXAgeMembers.Options; } }
```